# A question of sentence structure

Tags: british-english

> The government-issued passport is not up to international standards.

Or

> The passports issued by the government were not up to international standards .

Which sentence is appropriate to use?

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable.  The first is in present tense while the second is past tense, but I don't think that's what you're asking about.  (The second sentence could simply use *...by the government **are** not up to...* to match tense.)

The only real difference is in the use of *government-issued passport* versus *passport issued by the government*.

The second sentence is a little more formal, but is no better than the first.  I would probably use the first sentence because I'm a rather informal kinda guy.